# Redirect requests at a computer level

Tags: python, python-requests

In python, I have some other programs (not mine) that request to... lets say https://google.com. (Don't worry this isn't the real thing, its only used for other things)

I want all these requests to have the same data and everything, but sent to https://example.com.

Can I do it like something like this?

```
import psutil
def reqh(r):
    req=r
    req.url="https://example.com"
    req.data=req.data # same
    return req

psutil.on_request(reqh)
```

Maybe editing the hosts file would work, but I don't know how in python, or how to get the ip.

Comment: No, you can't, not something like that. If you can tell those programs to use a proxy server for their requests, then you could write one (though HTTPS will be somewhat tricky, for one) – or use e.g. `mitmproxy`.

Comment: No, I cant communicate with those. I think the host file would work the best.

Comment: How are you *calling* these "some other programs"? If they are in fact Python modules that you are calling from Python code, you could in theory [monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)  the `requests` module to perform the URL replacment you want, but if you are simply calling these other programs from the command line, then your only real option is a filtering proxy, as suggested by @AKX.

Comment: They are automatically ran. It is a game that redirects to a cdn and I am trying to change it so I have custom images. And I need it that way, not changing textures in the files (they dont exist)